# R reticulate unable to find installed python library

Tags: r, reticulate

I'm venturing into using Reticulate in R and having trouble installing a package, specifically `psycopg2` but I've also tried installing `twisted` with the same result.

after I load `reticulate` in R I double check to make sure my package is installed:

```
> conda_install(envname = "r-reticulate", packages="psycopg2")
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Looks good. So I set my condaenv to `r-reticulate` just to be double sure. The docs say I should not have to do this, but it should not hurt:

```
> use_condaenv( "r-reticulate")
```

Then I try to import `psycopg2`:

```
> psycopg2 <- import('psycopg2')
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

If I install `twisted` the same way, I get the same error:

```
> twisted <- import('twisted')
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: No module named twisted
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Below is the output of `conda_list` and `py_config`... I was expecting `py_config` to show me the path to the python exe in my `r-reticulate` environment. However I don't have anything to compare this to, so my expectations may have been wrong.

```
> conda_list()
          name                                                                              python
1     Anaconda                     C:\\Users\\jal\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\python.exe
2 r-reticulate C:\\Users\\jal\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\envs\\r-reticulate\\python.exe

> py_config()
python:         C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/jal/AppData/Local/CONTIN~1/Anaconda/python27.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda
version:        2.7.15 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.3
pandas:         C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\python.exe
 C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when using reticulate for the first time. Remove and recreated the `r-reticulate` conda environment from the shell solved my problem, see https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/253.

Comment: I have been struggling with this as well (on OS X) but none of these solutions worked.  I installed RStudio 1.2.x, I added RETICULATE_PYTHON=<pathto>/python3 to my .Renviron file, I removed and reinstalled conda env r-reticulate. I ran `conda_install('r-reticulate', 'psycopg2')` and same for 'numpy' but neither package shows up when I run `py_config()`.  `import('psycopg2')` and `import('numpy')` both result in "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named ..."

Comment: conda_install(...) installs every time I run it.  It doesn't recognize that packages are already installed.

Comment: In my case I had a ~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow folder from trying to install tensorflow.  Removal of that directory fixed the issue.

Comment: Restarting RStudio solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a whim I downloaded and installed the latest RStudio desktop (1.2.701) and upgraded from 1.1.442. This seems to have solved my issue. The packages load and I now see that when I run `py_config` I see paths that reflect my environment choice, as I would expect.

```
> py_config()
python:         C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/jal/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\envs\R-RETI~1
version:        3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.3
psycopg2:       C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\psycopg2

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe
 C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\Anaconda\python.exe
 C:\Users\jal\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
```

Comment: I could see the python versions by `py_config` but still no success. Just running in the correct environment from Terminal does the work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by following this way in RStudio:

> py_config()
> No non-system installation of Python could be found.
> Would you like to download and install Miniconda?
> Miniconda is an open source environment management system for Python.
> See https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html for more details.

Would you like to install Miniconda? [Y/n]: Y

- Downloading "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe" ...
  trying URL 'https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe'
  Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 57256056 bytes (54.6 MB)
  downloaded 54.6 MB
- Installing Miniconda -- please wait a moment ...

Comment: that's fine if you want you tu use the **conda environment**. in my case. for those using another virtual environment, as **pipenv** for instance, it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by following this way:

- Close RStudio.
- Open Terminal and **activate** your desired environment.
- Run RStudio by `$ open -na Rstudio`

Now you have your anac